# When does Rails generate a readme.md (as opposed to a readme.rdoc)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rdoc, readme

I noticed that when I generate a new rails app sometimes I end up with a readme.md and sometimes with a readme.rdoc (which Bitbucket doesnt automatically render apparentely).

If you've got any ideas about that, please let me know.

Comment: Different versions generate different formats, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `rails new` with [Rails 4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/command_line.html#rails-new) (or [Rails 3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/command_line.html#rails-new)) generates `README.rdoc`, while running it with [Rails 5 creates `README.md`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/command_line.html#rails-new).

This is listed in the [notable changes section](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#railties-notable-changes) of the Rails 5.0 release notes:

> - Newly generated applications and plugins get a README.md in Markdown. ([commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/89a12c931b1f00b90e74afffcdc2fc21f14ca663), [Pull Request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22068))